# extract substring and covert into float in a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop

This is the table that I have
[image]

I want to get just the age in number and put it in a new column. I know we'll use for loop but how.

Desired output[image]
In the column dob_num i want 33 and 30 in the next row

Answer (score 1):

If the ages are in the same format every time you can use the following code. Otherwise can use regex

```
    df['dob_num'] = [float(i[-3:-1]) for i in df.dob]
```

Comment: glad I could help.